# Spring Task Executor created extra threads in JUNIT

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, spring-integration

I have simple task executor in my spring-config.xml and couple of chains attached

```
      <channel id="inputChannel" />
    <task:executor id="threadPoolExecutor" pool-size="2" />
    <publish-subscribe-channel id="multiCastChannel"
        task-executor="threadPoolExecutor" />

    <chain input-channel="inputChannel"
        output-channel="multiCastChannel">
        <json-to-object-transformer
            type="com.company.integration.domain.DomainObject" />
        <service-activator ref="validator"
            method="validate" />
</chain>

<chain input-channel="multiCastChannel"
        output-channel="inventoryAdjustmentOutputChannelOne">
        <service-activator ref="adapterOne"
            method="buildOutputMessageOne" />
</chain>
<chain input-channel="multiCastChannel"
        output-channel="inventoryAdjustmentOutputChannelTwo">
        <service-activator ref="adapterTwo"
            method="buildOutputMessageTwo" />
</chain>
```

When a message posted to "inputChannel" and after processing and sent to "multuCastChannel" there are two threads created without issues like

**threadPoolExecutor-1**
**threadPoolExecutor-2**

And these two are created only once per input message which is fine.
But when I am trying to test the same with JUnit... each "multiCastChannel" chains are executing twice...***means my service activators (adapterOne,adapterTwo) in the chains are calling twice*** per chain ...which is wired..

Any idea why JUnit has this behavior ?

Below is the Junit piece of code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:configuration/spring-config.xml"})
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@WebAppConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class InventoryAdjustmentMessageTest {


    @Autowired
    private DirectChannel inputChannel;


    @Test
    public void testTaskShed()
            throws IOException, InterruptedException, JMSException {
        String validInput = setup("valid-message.txt");
        Message<String> inputMessage = TextMessageUtil.createNewGenericMessage(validInput);
        inputChannel.send(inputMessage);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
```

### }

***Spring integration version : 4.1.6***

Adding application config information:

```
@Import({ HarnessConfiguration.class, LocalConfiguration.class, MongoDbConfiguration.class, WebConfiguration.class,
        WebsphereMQJMSConfiguration.class })
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.abc.inventory.adjustment.integration.service",
        "com.abc.inventory.adjustment.integration.domain" }, useDefaultFilters = false, excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ApplicationConfiguration.class) }, includeFilters = {
                        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = { Controller.class,
                                Component.class }) })
@ImportResource({ "classpath:configuration/spring-config.xml", "classpath:configuration/spring-adapters.xml" })
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.abc.inventory.adjustment.integration.service.audit.repository")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
//
```

### }

Adding debug snapshot
[image: Extra threads for publish-subscribe channel in JUNIT]

-Tej

Comment: That does not make sense. Please, confirm that with some logs. Point out the Spring Integration version. How does it work without `taskExecutor`? How does it work without `@WebAppConfiguration`? Etc. etc.

Comment: Removed chains:     
<chain input-channel="multiCastChannel"  
        output-channel="inventoryAdjustmentOutputChannelOne">    
        <service-activator ref="adapterOne"    
            method="buildOutputMessageOne" />    
</chain>  
<chain input-channel="multiCastChannel"  
        output-channel="inventoryAdjustmentOutputChannelTwo">  
        <service-activator ref="adapterTwo"  
            method="buildOutputMessageTwo" />  
</chain>

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan
After analyzing step by step...came to know that whenever the message comes to "multiCastChannel" the subscribers are getting executed twice....I confirmed by removing all the subscriber chains 
and <task:executor> also and Just added a service activator like this:

<service-activator input-channel="multiCastChannel" ref="testAct"
   method="process" />


the process method called twice... I am going mad :(
Seems pub-sub channel has the issue...

Comment: OK. I would like to ask you to minimize it to something what I can test from my side and share here as an `edit` to your question. Thanks.

Comment: If  pub-sub channel had had an issue, we would know about that for a while already. As I said: you should prove that with some simple test case.

Comment: ok sure as I said the issue I am facing in JUNIT, I will cut the code and try to give you the logs here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find the simple test-case to demonstrate the proper behavior:

```
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="2"/>

<publish-subscribe-channel id="pubSubChannel" task-executor="executor" />

<service-activator input-channel="pubSubChannel" expression="T(System).out.println(payload)"/>

<service-activator input-channel="pubSubChannel" expression="T(System).out.println('foo: ' + payload)"/>
```

---

```
@Test
public void testPubSubChannel() throws InterruptedException {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("pubSubChannelConfig.xml", getClass());
    MessageChannel channel = (MessageChannel) context.getBean("pubSubChannel");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        channel.send(new GenericMessage<Integer>(i));
    }
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    context.close();
}
```

The result looks like:

```
foo: 0
0
foo: 1
1
2
foo: 2
3
foo: 3
4
foo: 4
5
foo: 5
6
foo: 6
7
foo: 7
8
foo: 8
9
foo: 9
```

Comment: Hi  @ArtemBilan, As you suggested I try to run a simple JUNIT with same requirement of mine...surprisingly it worked without issues..but coming to my application the issue still exist...Can you please shed some thoughts what can make <pub-sub channel> has this behavior....

Comment: Adding a bit of log
harness.jvm.memoryUsage.pools.Compressed-Class-Space.used is being registered as jvm_memoryUsage_pools_Compressed_Class_Space_used
2016-02-19T00:19:50.175Z [harness-metrics-collector STARTING] INFO  c.g.p.h.m.i.HarnessMetricListener - [] - metric name harness.logging..debug is being registered as logging_debug
2016-02-19T00:19:50.194Z [main] INFO  com.abc.service.TestActivator - [] - ********************activated*****************************
2016-02-19T00:19:50.195Z [main] INFO  com.abc.service.TestActivator - [] - ********************activated*****************************

Comment: I have just used a service activator which has sysout "******activated*****"
It is executed twice....I just observed by debug console that the main thread executed twice only for "service activator"....

Comment: Please, add DEBUG logs for the "org.springframework.integration" category to your question for analyze if wont be able to figure out an issue on yourself.

Comment: ok I am trying... I am new to threading concepts... so doing my best...Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan, After checking the entire application repo I came to know that the 'spring-config.xml' file is loaded twice in JUNIT Config ...which caused the actual issue... I removed the extra config..Now it looks good...